# How to combine multiple SQL queries on one table into one report

Tags: sql-server, report

I have looked at subqueries, unions, and joins.  They don't seem to be able to produce what I am looking for, or maybe I am not using them right.

I'm using SQL Server 2016.

Here is what I have. One table (`StoreScan`) with a row for store number and then a bunch of other rows with collected data on each store.

Example:

```
StoreNumber, uptime, service1status, service2status
```

Example data:

```
Storenumber     uptime    service1status    service2status  
-----------------------------------------------------------
 1              10        Running           Running
 18             25        Running           Stopped 
 88             3         Stopped           Running
 90             1         Running           Running
 103            5         Stopped           Running
 553            2         Running           Stopped
 989            2         Running           Running
```

I have several small queries like this:

```
select storenumber, uptime 
from storescan 
where uptime > 7


select storenumber, service1status 
from storescan 
where service1status = 'stopped'
```

I'd like to combine them all into one query for a report that would look something like this:

```
Storenumber     uptime    service1status    service2status  
-----------------------------------------------------------
1               10  
18              25  
88                        stopped  
103                       stopped  
553                                         stopped  
18                                          stopped
```

Comment: Hint: `Self Joins` or `Conditional Aggregation`

Comment: 1. Edit the question add some sample data too. 2. Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: Done.  See edits.

Answer (score 1):

Do *conditional* aggregation :

```
select Storenumber, 
       max(case when uptime > 7 then uptime end) as uptime,
       max(case when service1status = 'stopped' then service1status end),
       max(case when service2status = 'stopped' then service2status end)
from storescan ss 
group by Storenumber;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I see what you are doing here and I did give it a try.  My only issue with the output is that I'd rather it not list all the stores that don't meet the critera in the max case lines.  If a store has an uptime of less than 7 and all the services are running, I'd prefer it not be on the output.

Comment: @ScottSaxton Add `where not (uptime <=7 and service1status = 'running' and service2status = 'running'` after the `from`